# Tensorflow + Keras: constructing the composition of two networks

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I have loaded two networks using tensorflow and keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
net1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('net1.h5')
net2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('net2.h5')
```

I would like to construct the sequential composition of the two nets: the input goes through net1 (inputs of net1 have dimension 10), which outputs x, which is then fed to net2.
I wrote the following:

```
combined_netInput = Input(shape=(10,))
x = net1(combined_netInput)
combined_netOutput = net2(x)
combined_net = Model(inputs=combined_netInput, outputs=combined_netOutput)
combined_net.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))
```

The first line is rejected with the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adversarial_examples_pgd.py", line 28, in <module>
    x = net1(combined_netInput)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 634, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 247, in call
    return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 751, in call
    return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 893, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 663, in __call__
    inputs, outputs, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1708, in _set_connectivity_metadata_
    input_tensors=inputs, output_tensors=outputs, arguments=kwargs)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1795, in _add_inbound_node
    input_tensors)
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 515, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 515, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/home/nf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1794, in <lambda>
    inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've never seen this way of combining networks before, usually I use `net1.input` and `net1.output` to find the first and last layers so that I can combine architectures. However, I just created two dummy networks and connected them the way you show and everything works seems to work fine with your syntax... Though I used tf.keras instead of keras (don't know if that makes any difference to your issue)

Comment: Could you share your code? Thanks!